# Help with proof by induction?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Prove $\frac{2(n-c)}{n+1} < 2$ where c is any natural

So we assume $\frac{2(n-c)}{n+1} < 2$ is true, and so far I have
$\frac{2(n+1-c)}{n+2} = \frac{2n-2c+2}{n+2} = \frac{2(n-c)}{n+2} + \frac{2}{n+2}$
< $\frac{2(n-c)}{n+2} + 1$ < $\frac{2(n-c)}{n+1} + 1$

But the last term of the inequality is obviously bigger than two, so I am missing something in between, but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: Why use induction? Is that part of the assignment?

Comment: I just have to show the sequence is bounded above by 2 @DanielFischer

Comment: Then I'd start with $$\frac{2(n-c)}{n+1} < 2 \iff 2(n-c) < 2(n+1).$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\frac{2(n-c)}{n+1} = 2 - \frac{2(c+1)}{n+1}$. I assume you are saying this is true for $n$ in the natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

if $\frac {2(n-c)} {n+1}<2$ then $2n-2c<2n +2$ and hence $2+2c>0$. But $c\in \mathbb{N}$ hence this is always true.